# ¿Qué tiempo verbal es "veredes"?

Tags: tiempos-verbales, historia

Quien más o quien menos habrá leído la expresión "cosas veredes, amigo Sancho, que farán fablar las piedras". La frase se suele atribuir injustamente a El Quijote, cuando [en realidad es bastante más antigua](http://www.estandarte.com/noticias/idioma-espanol/la-expresion-cosas-veredes-_579.html).

Con independencia de su origen, la frase se suele entender como un *¡las cosas que hay que ver!* Pero siempre me ha quedado la siguiente duda: ¿qué tiempo verbal es (o fue) "veredes"? ¿Se puede equiparar con algún tiempo verbal actual?

Comment: Si no me equivoco, *tenedes* es una forma arcaica de la segunda persona del plural del presente de indicativo (es decir, equivalente al actual *tenéis*). La, ahora obsoleta, segunda persona del plural del portugués tenía una forma parecida  (*tendes*, pues la *e* se había perdido). Probablemente, *veredes* no ha existido nunca y fue una deformación, convirtiendo el presente de *tenedes* en futuro; así equivaldría a *veréis*; pero, como digo, no creo que nunca haya existido como palabra castellana, fuera de esa frase hecha.

Comment: Me suena que esto debe ser regional. ¿Tienes alguna referencia de uso en diversos países? Al menos nunca lo he escuchado en mi país.

Comment: @Ustanak pues la verdad es que no me lo había planteado. Buscando en Ngram veo que la expresión "cosas veredes" aparece en multitud de escritos... pero sólo a partir de principios del siglo XX. Tampoco es una expresión que haya oído mucho, sólo de vez en cuando y siempre en textos escritos. Puede que sí sea una corrupción de _tenedes_, como dice Gorpik, y la pregunta en realidad carezca de sentido.

Comment: @Gorpik sacado de El Quijote: _Agora valerosa compañía **veredes** quanto importa que aya en el mundo cavalleros que profesen la orden de la andante cavallería_. Se ve que el tiempo verbal sí existió. Aunque así dicho parece que, como decías, equivale a _veréis_.

Comment: @Gorpik tienes razón. La forma antigua de vosotros era [vocal temática] + DES.  Al perderse la D, subió la E a I. Las formas con D probablemente eran todavía comunes hasta el siglo XV o XVI en el habla, pero pervivieron en la escrita — sobre todo en poesía que incluso hoy en día es posible encontrar usos así a veces— por algo más. Es una forma que habrían conocido los lectores del Quijote, aún sin usarla ellos.

Comment: @CarlosAlejo Buen ejemplo, pero no sé si demostrativo. Don Quijote usa un lenguaje arcaizante, basado en lo que él había leído en sus libros de caballerías medievales. Por tanto, podría ser que Cervantes usara aquí una forma inexistente con fines satíricos.

Comment: Nunca había escuchado esa palabra como una forma verbal. Solamente como un adjetivo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[El apéndice al *Quijote* titulado "La lengua del *Quijote*: rasgos generales"](http://cvc.cervantes.es/literatura/clasicos/quijote/introduccion/apendice/gutierrez.htm), de Juan Gutierrez Cuadrado, que se halla en el Centro Virtual Cervantes, menciona [lo siguiente](http://cvc.cervantes.es/literatura/clasicos/quijote/introduccion/apendice/gutierrez02.htm):

> **12.9.** La segunda persona de plural de los tiempos verbales tenía en
>   latín una -t- que había evolucionado a -d- en castellano medieval.
>   Desde muy temprano, en las formas con acentuación llana la -d- se
>   perdió: *amades* pasó pronto a *amáis* y *temedes* a *teméis*. Sin embargo,
>   esta evolución fue más lenta en los tiempos esdrújulos. En estos
>   todavía en el Siglo de Oro se conserva la -d- < -t- etimológica
>   medieval: *aguardábades*, *alcanzáredes*, *alcanzásedes*, *amábades*,
>   *érades*, *estuviésedes*, *fuérades*, *habíades*, *hubiérades*,
>   *hubiéredes*, *íbades*, *podíades*, *pudiéredes*, *pusiéredes*,
>   *quedásedes*, *quisiéredes*, *quisiésedes*, *supiérades*, *supiésedes*,
>   *tardáredes*, *temíades*, *teníades*, *tocárades*, *veríades*,
>   *viéredes*, *volviéredes*, etc.
>
> **12.10.** Una representación ya escasa (arcaísmo evidente, como se desprende de
>   lo que hemos indicado en el punto anterior) es la de las formas de la
>   segunda persona de plural de los tiempos no esdrújulos que conservan
>   la -d-: *acuitedes* (que alterna con *acuitéis*); *fuyades* (que alterna con *fuyáis*); *habedes*, *hayades* (que alterna con *hayáis*); *ides*,
>   *mostredes*, *queredes*, *sepades*, *veredes*.

Esto no es propio de un solo tiempo verbal sino que corresponde a la terminación, ya que *veredes* equivaldría a *veréis* (futuro del indicativo), *fuyades* a *huyáis* (presente del subjuntivo), *teníades* de *teníais* (pasado del indicativo).
Más información al respecto se puede hallar en [Wikilengua](http://www.wikilengua.org/index.php/Formas_verbales_arcaicas) y en la [*Gramática de la lengua castellana*](https://books.google.com/books?id=I_AQB4mWNv8C&pg=PA99#v=onepage&q&f=false) en su edición de 1781.

Comment: "¡Non fuyades, cobardes y viles criaturas, que un solo caballero es el que os acomete!"